# Returning a Random nextBoolean in a user defined method accessed by switch case statement in java

Tags: random, boolean, switch-statement, case, java-7

I am trying to get my program to work the way I want. When I go in the switch statement I want to have the user type in a value and go to that corresponding user createdmethod. When in one of the user created method I have a random boolean value returned to the main method. I want my program to only println "key is here" when the value is true and ONLY for the one method I accessed, not all of the methods. Because when I run the program it will go through all the methods in the if statements and not just the one i want. Can someone please help me? I want to keep the user created methods returning nextBoolean and have the println "key is here" to be in the main method still. Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance. I'm a total beginner at this :)
Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class JavaGameSearchHouse
{
    public static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static boolean keyValue;
    public static Random keyVal = new Random();
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String roomValue;
        int counter;
        int keepGoing = 0;

        do{
            System.out.println("Lets search this house for the key");
            roomValue = console.next();

            switch(roomValue.toLowerCase())
            {

            case "kitchen": kitchenMethod();
            break;
            case "bedroom": bedroomMethod();
            break;
            case "familyRoom": familyRoomMethod();
            break;
            case "livingRoom": livingRoomMethod();
            break;
            case "bathroom": bathroomMethod();
            break;
            case "basement": basementMethod();
            break;
            default: System.exit(0);
            }


            if(kitchenMethod())
                System.out.println("Key is here1");

            if(bedroomMethod())
                System.out.println("Key is here2");

            if(familyRoomMethod())
                System.out.println("Key is here3");

            if(livingRoomMethod())
                System.out.println("Key is here4");

            if(bathroomMethod())
                System.out.println("Key is here5");

            if(basementMethod())
                System.out.println("Key is here6");


            System.out.println("press 1 to search again");
            keepGoing = console.nextInt();
        }while(keepGoing == 1);
    }

    public static boolean kitchenMethod()
    {
        return keyVal.nextBoolean();
    }

    public static boolean bedroomMethod()
    {
        return keyVal.nextBoolean();
    }

    public static boolean familyRoomMethod()
    {
        return keyVal.nextBoolean();
    }

    public static boolean livingRoomMethod()
    {
        return keyVal.nextBoolean();
    }

    public static boolean bathroomMethod()
    {
        return keyVal.nextBoolean();
    }

    public static boolean basementMethod()
    {
        return keyVal.nextBoolean();
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @Bohemian Yes I am using java7

Answer (score 1):

You could just run your methods in the switch and remove the if statements at the end :

```
           case "kitchen": if(kitchenMethod())
                System.out.println("Key is here1");
            break;
            case "bedroom": if(bedroomMethod())
                System.out.println("Key is here2");
            break;
            case "familyRoom": if(familyRoomMethod())
                System.out.println("Key is here3");
            break;
            case "livingRoom": if(livingRoomMethod())
                System.out.println("Key is here4");
            break;
            case "bathroom": if(bathroomMethod())
                System.out.println("Key is here");
            break;
            case "basement": if(basementMethod())
                System.out.println("Key is here6");
            break;
            default: System.exit(0);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The *method* that is accessed should print the value, not the `if` statement.

```
   public static boolean kitchenMethod()
    {
        Boolean key = keyVal.nextBoolean();
        if (key)
          System.out.println("Key is here1");
        return key;
    }
```

do it for other methods and remove `if` statements.

Comment: I think you mean `boolean` not `Boolean`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the switch. Your approach calls the room methods every time, even if not required.

Instead, do this:

```
if(roomValue.equalsIgnoreCase("kitchen") && kitchenMethod()) {
    System.out.println("Key is here1");
}
```

Etc.

This approach will only call the room method if required.

---

Alternatively, you could embed the if statements inside the switch, but it would make for some ugly code.